# Is there a way to improve a MERGE query?

Tags: python, oracle

I using this query to insert new entries to my table

```sql
MERGE INTO CLEAN clean USING DUAL ON (clean.id = :id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, COUNT) VALUES (:id, :xcount)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET clean.COUNT = clean.count + :xcount
```

It seems that I do more `insert`s than `update`s, is there a way to improve my current performance?

I am using cx_Oracle with Python 3 and OracleDB 19c.

Comment: You problem is not caused by the `MERGE` statement, but due to the fact that you are calling it **in the loop** - so called *row by row aka slow by slow*. You must change it to the call of *one* `MERGE` statement, where you replace the `dual` with the *temporary table* containg all the rows to be processed.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, could you explain more? I didn't quite understand

Comment: Well there is a big difference is fou call *one* `MERGE` to process 1M rows (= quick) or one *million* times a `MERGE` statement to process *one rows* (= much slower and your case).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Is there a way I can do it from python? I am just using execute_many

Comment: For sure there will be a way, post the whole statement, so the logic is visible...

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, this is the while statement. I just pass `execute_many` a dict with all the data

Comment: Yes I understood. You are dooing nothing wrong, but you should expect 20-30 secs to merge 1M rows. Is this something you are observing? Pls check my answer for further posibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would have a *massive* problems with you approach, you are very probably missing an index on the column `clean.id`, that is required for your approach when the `MERGE` uses `dual` as a source for each row.

This is less probable while you are saying the `id` is a *primary key*.

So *basically* you are doing the right think and you will see [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) similar as the one below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT                 |                 |       |       |     2 (100)|          |
|   1 |  MERGE                          | CLEAN           |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                          |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                 |     1 |    40 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL           | DUAL            |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     VIEW                        | VW_LAT_A18161FF |     1 |    38 |     0   (0)|          |
|   6 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CLEAN           |     1 |    38 |     0   (0)|          |
|*  7 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | CLEAN_UX1       |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   7 - access("CLEAN"."ID"=:ID)
```

So the execution plan is fine and works effectively, but it has one problem.

Remember **always you use an index, you will be happy while processing few rows, but it will not scale**.

If you are processing a *millions* of records, you may fall back to a two step processing,

- insert all rows in a temporary table
- perform a single `MERGE` statement using the temporary table

The *big advantage* is that Oracle can open a `hash join` and get rid of the index access for each of the *million* rows.

Here an example of a test of the `clean` table initiated with 1M `id` (not shown) and performing 1M insert and 1M updates:

```
n  = 1000000
data2 = [{"id" : i, "xcount" :1} for i in range(2*n)]  

sql3 = """
    insert into tmp (id,count)
    values (:id,:xcount)"""
sql4 = """MERGE into clean USING tmp on (clean.id = tmp.id)
          when not matched then insert (id, count)  values (tmp.id, tmp.count)
          when matched then update set clean.count= clean.count + tmp.count"""    

cursor.executemany(sql3, data2)
cursor.execute(sql4)
```

The test runs in aprox. 10 second, which is less than a half of you approach with `MERGE`using `dual`.

If this is still not enough, you'll have to use *parallel option*.

Comment: Glad to be able to help @john

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` is quite fast. Inserts being faster then updates, I'd say (usually).

So, if you're asking how to make inserts faster, then it depends.

- If you're inserting one row at a time, there shouldn't be any bottleneck.
- If you're inserting *millions of rows*, see whether there are triggers enabled on the table which fire for each row and *do something* (slowing the process down).

As of updates, is there index on `clean.id` column? If not, it would probably help.

Otherwise, see what explain plan says; collect statistics regularly.

Comment: `clean.id` is the primary key and there aren't any triggers. How can I get the explain from python?

Comment: I wouldn't know; it is much closer to Oracle than Python and I get it from e.g. SQL Developer or TOAD (or even SQL*Plus) - in other words, tools I use to access my Oracle database. As of ID being the primary key, it also means that there's an unique index on that column as well so - yes, it is indexed.

Comment: BTW, @Marmite Bomber nicely explained it in their answer.